# CakePHP - Query not returning strange characters from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a MySQL table of countries, which includes some country names that have strange characters like 'Åland Islands'.

When I perform a CakePHP find on all countries, the rows with strange characters just come back blank.  My table and column collation is utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Do you have in your Config/database.php `'encoding' => 'utf8',` in `$default`?

Comment: No, it was commented out by default!  That was the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was, as tigrang said, in Config/database.php you must have 'encoding' => 'utf8'

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the output of your displaying is set to UTF-8
make sure that the page through which you input the data is set to UTF-8 so it doesn't send the data as ANSI or something else.

You could set up a little test page that you're sure off to enter the data in UTF-8 and displays in UTF-8 as well, then at least you'll know wether it's related to display or previous methods of data entry.